# Grouping age in Pandas (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, grouping, frequency

I have a DataFrame with column "ages" and column "professional qualification", like this:

| ages | professional qualification |
| --- | --- |
| 45 | labourer |
| 49 | labourer |
| 29 | labourer |
| 61 | labourer |
| 45 | labourer |
| 37 | labourer |
| 17 | office worker |
| 56 | labourer |
| 47 | office worker |

I want to group the ages like this ( ,17), (17,29), (30,40), (40,50), (50, )
and, with these ages grouped I would to create a frequency table indicating on each age group what professional qualification appears more often.

Example:

| ages | professional qualification |
| --- | --- |
| (,17) | office worker |
| (17,29) | labourer |
| (30,40) | labourer |
| (40,50) | labourer |

etc, etc, etc.
The people who have an age between 40 and 50 (excluding 40) are mostly labourers

All solutions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) with aggregate by [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) custom function by [`Series.mode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mode.html) with select first element:

```
bins = [0,17,29,40,50,70,100]

f = lambda x: x.mode().iat[0]
df1 = (df.groupby(pd.cut(df['ages'], bins=bins))['professional qualification']
         .agg(f)
         .reset_index())
print (df1)
        ages professional qualification
0    (0, 17]              office worker
1   (17, 29]                   labourer
2   (29, 40]                   labourer
3   (40, 50]                   labourer
4   (50, 70]                   labourer
5  (70, 100]                       None
```